# Can I do complex statements in flashcardSearchQuery?

Tags: java, android, sql

Right now I have a very simple SQL query that checks whether 3 conditions are true:

```html
        String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                COLUMN_KNOW_FOREIGN_CHAR + " = 0 AND " +
                COLUMN_KNOW_FOREIGN_ALT + " = 0 AND " +
                COLUMN_KNOW_ENGLISH_WORD + " = 0";
```

Now I want to add one more, where I utilize a 4th SQL variable (COLUMN_SLEEP_DATE) but I want to check it against the current date and see how many days it has been i.e. get the delta between the current date and the stored date.
I'm not sure if that's doable in a `flashcardSearchQuery` statement, so before I try to make this work, maybe someone can tell me if I'm on the right path or whether I should simple do that outside of SQL ?

this is what I would have to embed somehow: (or something similar)

```html
        Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date rightNow = calendarNow.getTime();
        long diff = 0;
        try {
            diff = Math.round((rightNow.getTime() -
                    df.parse(flashcard.getSleepDate()).getTime()) / (double) 86400000);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
```